# How to prevent JComboBox from becoming unresponsive when using a custom ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I am making a font chooser using `JComboBox` and a custom `ListCellRenderer`. I want
the `JComboBox` to display all available fonts, with each font name displayed in its own font. I am currently using around 500 fonts.

An example of a `ListCellRenerer` that provides this functionality:

```
private class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        Font tempFont = label.getFont();
        setFont(new Font((String) value, tempFont.getStyle(),
                tempFont.getSize()));

        setText((String) value);

        return this;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when using this renderer, the `JComboBox` becomes unresponsive during program execution. The first time one clicks on the combobox to reveal the list, it takes a couple of seconds for the list to load. The second time one clicks, the list is instantly displayed.

If one comments the line

```
setFont(new Font((String) value, tempFont.getStyle(),tempFont.getSize()));
```

, the combobox works just fine.

How can one prevent this unresponsiveness?

Comment: You might want to try creating a cache of `Font` objects. Used to cache `Font` and `FontMetric` back in the 90s. You could go for creating a `JLabel` for each `Font`.

Comment: but with test `if (isSelected){` or `cellHasFocus`

Comment: Just noticed you say it is only slow the first time and you are using 500 fonts. I guess loading 500 fonts is quite a task.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - don't think so, as commenting the line which creates the _display font_ helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that the combo's internals try to find the preferred size dynamically. For doing so, it loops through all items in the list, feeds the renderer with the items to measure the rendering component's preferred size.

You can prevent that by setting a prototypeValue for measuring, then the size is measured once using that prototype

```
 comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue(sampleFont);
```

Edit: as @Boro detected, that's not enough - it sets the prototype for the comboBox itself only, not for the list in the popup (as it should, how crazily buggy can that ... possibly be). To hack around, we have to manually set it, here's a code snippet to play with

```
public class ComboWithPrototype {

    private JComponent createContent() {
        final Font[] systemFonts = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();

        final JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
        box.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());
        box.setPrototypeDisplayValue(systemFonts[0]);
        Accessible a = box.getUI().getAccessibleChild(box, 0);
        if (a instanceof javax.swing.plaf.basic.ComboPopup) {
            JList popupList = ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.ComboPopup) a).getList();
            // route the comboBox' prototype to the list
            // should happen in BasicComboxBoxUI
            popupList.setPrototypeCellValue(box.getPrototypeDisplayValue());
        }
        Action action = new AbstractAction("set model") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                box.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(systemFonts));
            }
        };
        JComponent panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(box);
        panel.add(new JButton(action), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ComboWithPrototype().createContent());
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Custom ListCellRenderer (slightly changed, to expect items of type Font)

```
private class ComboBoxRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private Font baseFont = new JLabel("Test").getFont();

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
                cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof Font) {

            Font font = (Font) value;
            setFont(new Font(font.getName(), baseFont.getStyle(), baseFont.getSize())); 
            setText(font.getName());
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra can you show an example how it is used as I am trying to use it and no luck. Always have delay independent of setting it before or after installing renderer. `Font[] opts = new Font[]{....};
    JComboBox p = new JComboBox(opts);    
    p.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());
    p.setPrototypeDisplayValue(largestFont);` I can post SSCCE if required though I changed the render's body.

Comment: @Boro - f*, you're right, setting that property doesn't seem to be enough: it prevents the loop through all values for sizing the _combo_ itself, but still loops when showing the popup ...

Comment: @kleopatra Yea that is what I experienced.

Comment: @kleopatra Nice this is it (+1 for this). There is still very very slight delay before the list shows initially but I reckon it is because it is being being for the first time. All together this solution is much faster then without it. Good job.

Comment: @Boro - thanks :-) Hmm ... don't see _any_ delay (and actually shouldn't, it's only showing 8 or so items) - maybe machine-dependent? Note to myself: try on Netbook

Comment: @kleopatra you might be well right as to the machine dependent issue. To be precise after some testing using popuplistener on the combobox popup and global mouse click listener. It appears that without your code it takes around 4.5s initially and 1ms after. Where with your code it takes around 1s initially and 1ms after. Tested on CoreDuo 2.4 GHz Win7.

Comment: @Boro .. strange, my context is about the same and I don't see _any_ (read zero, zilch, nada :-) delay when opening the combo. Just to be sure we talk about the same: show the ui (fonts in the array, but combo still empty), trigger the action to set the combo's model (happens instantly), click on the combo-down-arrow to open the popup (happens instantly).

Comment: @kleopatra I think so. Maybe you can share your class so I can check against? It might be that I did some weird stuff.

Comment: @Boro, it's nothing special - simply add the barest glue to the snippets and throw all the components (the combo, a button bound to the action) into a frame and be done

Comment: @kleopatra That is what I did. And what I have observed it doesn't change a thing if you add the model on run time or at start. In both cases it works the same, always very very slight delay at first. Anyway no bother it is not bad considering possible alternative of 5s :)

Comment: @Boro - changed the snippet to be nearer to a compilable/runnalbe. Out off ideas as to the difference (personally, I don't think of a 1s delay as "very very slight", everything more than a few tens of millis is perceptible and anything perceptible is bad ;-) Last try: what's your jdk version? Mine is 6u25

Comment: was wrong, my jdk is 6u24 ;-) Not that I expect much of a difference between u24 and u25, just to be precise

Comment: @kleopatra Still no good. 1s delay always at initial. mine jdk was 6u11 but updated to 6u25 and still the same.

Comment: @Boro - any special default LAF? can you add a logging println in the renderer and verify that it's called eight times (visible rows in the list) or so when opening the poppup?

Comment: @kleopatra I am not setting any LAF. The getLookAndFeel() returns `UIManager.getLookAndFeel()=[The Java(tm) Look and Feel - javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel]`. The line added to the render `System.out.println("counter="+counter++);` prints initially up to `counter=5`, then installing the model prints up to `counter=7` then show combox popup action prints up to `counter=37`. Any idea? What is your LAF? Thanks v.much for your interest in this problem. Would be nice if someone else could say if it is also present at their machine or not.

Answer (score -1):

@kleopatra than you for notice me but `setPrototypeDisplayValue` look like as lazy choise, my amedment

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;

public class SystemFontDisplayer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JComboBox fontsBox;

    public SystemFontDisplayer() {

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fontFamilyNames = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        fontsBox = new JComboBox(fontFamilyNames);
        fontsBox.setSelectedItem(0);
        fontsBox.setRenderer(new ComboRenderer(fontsBox));
        fontsBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    final String fontName = fontsBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    fontsBox.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 16));
                }
            }
        });
        fontsBox.setSelectedItem(0);
        fontsBox.getEditor().selectAll();
        add(fontsBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 60));
        setLocation(200, 105);
        pack();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                fontsBox.setPopupVisible(true);
                fontsBox.setPopupVisible(false);
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SystemFontDisplayer systemFontDisplayer = new SystemFontDisplayer();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ComboRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JComboBox comboBox;
        final DefaultListCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
        private int row;

        private ComboRenderer(JComboBox fontsBox) {
            comboBox = fontsBox;
        }

        private void manItemInCombo() {
            if (comboBox.getItemCount() > 0) {
                final Object comp = comboBox.getUI().getAccessibleChild(comboBox, 0);
                if ((comp instanceof JPopupMenu)) {
                    final JList list = new JList(comboBox.getModel());
                    final JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu) comp;
                    final JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) popup.getComponent(0);
                    final JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
                    final Rectangle rect = popup.getVisibleRect();
                    final Point pt = viewport.getViewPosition();
                    row = list.locationToIndex(pt);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (list.getModel().getSize() > 0) {
                manItemInCombo();
            }
            final JLabel renderer = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, row, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            final Object fntObj = value;
            final String fontFamilyName = (String) fntObj;
            setFont(new Font(fontFamilyName, Font.PLAIN, 16));
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for (unsuccessfully) trying to re-invent the wheel. Read the api doc of setPrototypeDisplayVaule to learn that it's there for exactly the reason it's needed here, that is to _not_ loop through all elements just for getting at the size hints

Comment: another -1 for doing completely unswing-ish things like (incomplete list): a) let the renderer have a reference to the target comboBox b) create a JList in every call to getRendererComponent,  c) configure an unused renderer on each call ...

Comment: @ kleopatra :-) this Renderer works without Loop inside JList :-), its about my lazyness to remove calling manItemInCombo();

Comment: @kleopatra - I'm thinking of an upvote for mKorbel... ;-) because his solution sets different heights for the font-listentries, your solution sets the same (maybe too small, but sure too big for some fonts) height for all entries.