# How to get the number of columns and rows that are visible in my JList?

Tags: java, swing, pagination, jscrollpane, jlist

I have a `JList` that is inside of a `JscrollPane` and I am trying to do some pagination on the data, in which as the user scrolls it loads the appropriate amount of data onto the screen.  The problem is I need to figure out how much data I need to buffer out of my file and the only way to do that is to figure out how much data needs to be displayed on the screen.  Does anyone have an idea of how to get the number or rows and columns that can be displayed out of my `JList`? Also is doing pagination with a `JList` and a `JScrollPane` a good idea or is there some other approach that would be better suited for displaying a ton of data in a scroll panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getFirstVisibleIndex` and `getLastVisibleIndex` methods of `JList` to calculate number of items it displays when visible.

If size of viewport in scroll pane changes then the number of visible rows will also change. So if the component is resizable you may need to listen to the change in the component size.

Comment: +1 right, another examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911865/jcombobox-determine-if-items-are-arent-visible-in-drop-down-list

Answer (score 2):

Do `getModel()` on the JList to get the underlying `ListModel`, then call `getSize()` on it.

EDIT: oh, and if the model contents consist of a datastructure with multiple columns, call whatever suitable method exists on that for the size. You can get a row with `getElementAt(int index)`. Might require some more work if the column count is variable.

Comment: Yea but in order to do that my ListModel would already have to be loaded with data that I buffered in?  I would like to know before putting the data in how much the view can hold.

Comment: Ah, didn't interpret your question all that well. If I were you, I wouldn't bother trying to find out exactly how much data can be displayed. Just load a solid batch, enough to fill up a couple screens, then use some sort of scroll listener scheme to load in more as you scroll down.

Comment: You can also load data based on the call to getElementAt() of the ListModel so you can load next page.

Comment: @G_H I hadn't thought of that, and it's a great idea, Thanks!

Comment: I think AKJ's answer merits some investigation. Sounds like it'll offer exactly what you need. But maybe be careful with loading in additional rows every time you scroll down, might slow things a bit. Getting some extra stuff in the buffer ahead of time seems reasonable.