# JTree: speed up drawing of 1000+ children nodes from objects retrieved from database?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

When I retrieve 1000+ java objects from the database, it is done very quickly. I end up with `List<Object>` matching my query.

The problem is drawing these objects onto the `Jtree`.

For example, I have a parentID of a given node. When this node (`DefaultMutableTreeNode`) is double clicked (`TreeMouseListener.class`), it will display direct children of this node, not all descendants (although this might be required later if possible but not right now).

The problem is that this jtree drawing operation takes very long time to complete adding 1000+ children `DefaultMutableTreeNodes` for the selected parent node.

ex) 1000 of `new DefaultMutableTreeNode(Person person);`

How can this drawing process be sped up?

I am not using any custom cell renderer nor am I displaying anything other than small bits of text for each node.

Comment: Some of the stuff in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893162/how-to-get-the-number-of-columns-and-rows-that-are-visible-in-my-jlist) might prove relevant to yours.

Comment: im writing this as comment as i dont wanna bump it. but the reason i was facing slowness was becuse i was using a remote database server. when i used local database, the pr0oblem was gone.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to time where the slowdown is but I doubt it is just creating DefaultMutableTreeNodes which should be faster than loading the Person objects from the database. It's unlikely to be the painting (unless your Person#toString() is very slow) since there won't be a thousand nodes on the screen.

My guess is that you are adding the nodes one-by-one, causing a thousand change events instead of adding all the children at once. You should add the thousand child nodes to the parent node directly and then call DefaultTreeModel#nodeStructureChanged(node) on the parent node.

If that is still slow, it's time for a SSCCE. For example, pressing the button on my system shows no delay at all:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class TestJTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
                final DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTree(model)));
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(
                        new AbstractAction("Add thousand children") {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int offset = root.getChildCount() + 1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
                                    "Person " + (i + offset));
// adding child with event (but isn't much slower really)
//                                model.insertNodeInto(child, root, root.getChildCount());
                            root.add(child);
                        }
                        model.nodeStructureChanged(root);
                    }
                }), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you add thousand child nodes directly without adding them one by one in a loop?

Comment: Actually tested with DefaultTreeModel#insertNodeInto (commented out in SSCCE) and I can't notice a difference in speed. So if you see a difference in your code, it's definitely not Swing that is the problem. Better fire up VisualVM to see where the problem is in your code.

Comment: Ah, I do start to notice a slowdown with 1000xinsertNodeInto after pressing the button 15 times or so. The nodeStructureChanged way remains the same speed for me until 50 clicks (as in 50k nodes) or so and then it's still much faster then after 15 click with insert.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably creating 1000+ DefaultMutableTreeNodes to put your List in.  The problem is creating that many objects quickly, and translating your objects to DefaultMutableTreeNode.  If you don't create all of those objects you can improve your performance.  I'd suggest just writing your own implementation of TreeModel that works directly with your object model so you don't have to recreate that many objects over again.  That should improve your speed dramatically.  I've put 10,000 objects in JTree before (I did it but it probably wasn't that great an idea), but I had to write my own TreeModel so I didn't have to recreate those objects.

However, as with all performance problems you should profile it first to figure out where you are spending time and address that issue.  If it turns out it's this problem then you can do that.  You don't need to try and create your own graphics drawing routines because that's significantly more work than writing your own TreeModel.

Another option is to fetch the tree on demand as it's needed.  So fetch the root then as the user expands each node fetch its children from the server.  The user can't look at all 1000+ nodes at once anyway so this will dramatically reduce the amount you are transferring over the network and less time spent on the server.

Comment: so do you mean to just create "empty" defaultmutabletreenodes?

Comment: No.  DefaultMutableTreeNode implements two interfaces MutableTreeNode and TreeNode.  Your objects that are being sent from the server can implement TreeNode or MutableTreeNode and JTree can use them directly instead of DefaultMutableTreeNode.  You'll need to create your own implementer of TreeModel as well to hand out references to your implementations of TreeNode/MutableTreeNode.  Read the javadoc on this, and google on the web how to do this there are plenty of documents out there.

Comment: list<object> contain objects stored in object database. cannot store objects that implement TreeNode only POJO. Once the list<object> is retrieved, I should create another list<DefaultMutableTreeNode> containing those objects? because I don't understand how I can create an "implementer" on the fly other than doing `new DefaultMutableTreeNode(object)`....did you mean `object implements MutableTreeNode` and storing this directly? sorry for the confusion. I also am trying this method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962252/jtree-how-to-hide-parts-of-a-given-defaultmutabletreenodes-text

Comment: Creating thousands of DefaultMutableTreeNode objects quickly is unlikely to be the problem since that is what loading them from the database does as well (Person objects, which are likely more complex than DefaultMutableTreeNode) which the OP claims is fast.

Comment: @Kim What I meant was the object you are storing to the OODB would implement MutableTreeNode or TreeNode.  It will still be a POJO.  If you don't want to do that then the other option is to be lazy about creating TreeNode/MutableTreeNode.  JTree will only request TreeNodes for the things that are visible.  You could easily create an implementation of TreeNode that waits to create it's children until someone asks for them too if you don't want your POJO to implement TreeNode.

Comment: @Walter True whatever is creating the original 1000+ objects is creating that many objects quickly could be replicated.  My main point was you're doing this twice.  1000 * 2 = 2 * N.  If you want a 100% increase in speed stop creating so many objects.  I bet there is something in how the DefaultMutableTreeNodes are created that is slow, but as with all perf problems you gotta profile to confirm.  Remember DefaultMutableTreeNode is old as hell and uses Vectors internally which are fully synchronized which can be slow too.

Answer (score -3):

Write your own JTree using a JPanel for graphics :P.

Or you can make a class extending JTree and override the `paint(Graphics g)` method