# Jtree: how to hide parts of a given defaultmutabletreenode's text?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Say my JTree consists of following nodes.

`new DefaultMutableTreeNode("DisplayThisTextOnly {donotdisplaystringsinhere}");`

how can I hide the texts between and including {} from displaying using `TreeCellRenderer`?

when I select this node, I want to be able to fetch the entire string again.

`"DisplayThisTextOnly {donotdisplaystringsinhere}"`

Basically my goal is to be able to fetch additional data from a given tree node without having to `setObject()`

Comment: You mean you want to have additional data from the TreeNode by parsing the text string??!  Don't do that.  That's crazy.  Just call setObject() on DefaultMutableTreeNode, and call getObject() to get your object back.  That'll save you lots of time.  You created these objects to help you organize your data efficiently.  Then parsing this stuff like this is throwing all of your work to create these objects out the window.  Save yourself from yourself.

Comment: If you need your TreeNode to store more than one object then put them into a container and store the container as the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom renderer and strip out the text you don't want to see. The section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Trees](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) has an example renderer to get you started.