# Swing - Remove selected border and change arrow color of JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm trying to remove the selected border of a JComboBox (top arrow) and change the arrow color (bottom arrow)

If possible, how do I remove the outer border? (the darker gray one)

[image]

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you use any Look And Feel?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. no, i don't

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this by implementing a `ComboBoxUI`, or, actually, subclassing `BasicComboBoxUI` for example. The second option is better, because you only need to tweak some code in some places and you are ready (instead of implementing your own `ComboBoxUI` from scratch). So follows the code which does what you requested (hopefully):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicArrowButton;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI;

public class MainComboBoxUI {
    public static class MyComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {
        @Override
        protected void installDefaults() {
            super.installDefaults();
            LookAndFeel.uninstallBorder(comboBox); //Uninstalls the LAF border for both button and label of combo box.
        }

        @Override
        protected JButton createArrowButton() {
            //Feel free to play with the colors:
            final Color background = Color.CYAN.darker();     //Default is UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.buttonBackground").
            final Color pressedButtonBorderColor = Color.RED; //Default is UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.buttonShadow"). The color of the border of the button, while it is pressed.
            final Color triangle = Color.BLACK;               //Default is UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.buttonDarkShadow"). The color of the triangle.
            final Color highlight = background;               //Default is UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.buttonHighlight"). Another color to show the button as highlighted.
            final JButton button = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.SOUTH, background, pressedButtonBorderColor, triangle, highlight);
            button.setName("ComboBox.arrowButton"); //Mandatory, as per BasicComboBoxUI#createArrowButton().
            return button;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"A string", "B string 2", "C string 3"});
        combo.setUI(new MyComboBoxUI());

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(combo);
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED.darker());

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainComboBoxUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

First of, we remove the border from the combo box inside `installDefaults()` method. That will remove the border from both the button and the label. Then we mimic the `createArrowButton()` method of `BasicComboBoxUI` to create our own custom button. The default implementation of `BasicComboBoxUI.createArrowButton()` creates a `BasicArrowButton` with some construction-time colors. Those colors change the button's triangle's color for example and the background color.

That is for creating a `BasicArrowButton`. Although, if you want better control over the button (for example instead of a triangle you need an icon and/or some text on the button) then you can simply create a plain `JButton` inside the `createArrowButton()` instead of a `BasicArrowButton`. Then you can initialize it inside the same method, or, preferably modify it inside the `configureArrowButton()`. Like the following code does:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI;

public class MainComboBoxUI2 {
    public static class MyComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {
        @Override
        protected void installDefaults() {
            super.installDefaults();
            LookAndFeel.uninstallBorder(comboBox);
        }

        @Override
        protected JButton createArrowButton() {
            final JButton button = new JButton("V");
            button.setName("ComboBox.arrowButton"); //Mandatory, as per BasicComboBoxUI#createArrowButton().
            return button;
        }

        @Override
        public void configureArrowButton() {
            super.configureArrowButton(); //Do not forget this!
            arrowButton.setBackground(Color.CYAN.darker());
            arrowButton.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"A string", "B string 2", "C string 3"});
        combo.setUI(new MyComboBoxUI());
        combo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 45)); //Needed to be able to show the button's text.

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(combo);
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED.darker());

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainComboBoxUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The only problem with the custom plain `JButton` approach (ie the second approach) is that the `LayoutManager` of the `JComboBox` will not take into account the preferred size of the arrow button if a protected flag inside the UI (named *squareButton*) is `true`. If that flag is `true`, then the button's width is set equal to the button's height, which in turn is set equal to the combo box height. That's why in the second approach, I set the preferred size of the combo box manually to give it a height of 45 pixels which is enough to be able to display the text inside the button (in that specific case, where the text is equal to "V").

You can set the value of this flag for a single UI instance manually by overriding `installDefaults()` method in the `BasicComboBoxUI` and setting it to `false` for example. Otherwise, you can set its value for all combo boxes via calling `UIManager.put("ComboBox.squareButton", Boolean.FALSE);` in your code early enough (ie before the instantiation of each combo box). But as it turns out, because I tested it, when setting this value to `false` the size of the button overlaps the display area's size (the *display area* is where the selected value of the combo box is visible).

After some more digging, I found out that the cause of this problem is that the UI's `getMinimumSize(...)` method does not take into account the button's insets... That means the default border of the `JButton` around the text/icon is not accounted for. So after setting the *squareButton* flag to `false`, you will also need to override this method.

Putting them all together, you get the following final approach/code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI;

public class MainComboBoxUI3 {
    public static class MyComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {
        @Override
        protected void installDefaults() {
            super.installDefaults();
            LookAndFeel.uninstallBorder(comboBox);
        }

        @Override
        protected JButton createArrowButton() {
            final JButton button = new JButton("Drop");
            button.setName("ComboBox.arrowButton"); //Mandatory, as per BasicComboBoxUI#createArrowButton().
            return button;
        }

        @Override
        public void configureArrowButton() {
            super.configureArrowButton(); //Do not forget this!
            arrowButton.setBackground(Color.CYAN.darker());
            arrowButton.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            //arrowButton.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        }

        //Overrided getMinimumSize to take into account the button's insets for both width and height:
        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize(final JComponent c) {
            final Dimension mindim = super.getMinimumSize(c);
            final Insets buttonInsets = arrowButton.getInsets();
            return new Dimension(mindim.width + buttonInsets.left + buttonInsets.right, mindim.height + buttonInsets.top + buttonInsets.bottom);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.squareButton", Boolean.FALSE); //Set all the combo boxes' button to non-square...
        final JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"A string", "B string 2", "C string 3"});
        combo.setUI(new MyComboBoxUI());

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(combo);
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED.darker());

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainComboBoxUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: Combo Box final approach result]

Finally, if you want smaller border for the drop down button (ie the one with text "Drop" in the above picture), you can set the border of the `arrowButton` to (for example) `javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()` inside the `configureArrowButton()` method...

Comment: It's not white. I double checked. It might be the contrast with the *Color.RED.darker()* you see from the background *panel*. Try setting the background *panel* color to white, and you will see the difference.

Comment: well either way I can't set the background of the box now - so how would I fix that?

Comment: @Auxilor this can be done via the UIManager. See from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11420371/6746785) answer, from the "Edit 2" part, the lines of code in the *main* method.

Comment: @Auxilor Although *combo.setBackground(Color.GREEN);* worked! You just need to lose focus from the combo box. Try adding other combonents (like buttons) and click them to change focus, and now, when the combo box doesn't have focus, the green background is visible. It is not visible at the code I provided because there are no other components to take the focus... Notify me if you don't see what I mean.