# How to modify font family in JComboBox value?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` which populate font name. Like this image :

[image]

How to change the font family in `JComboBox` value according to font name?

Answer (score 3):

You can [use a custom cell renderer for the ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer), where you can return a JLabel to be displayed in JComboBox, and in renderer's method you can change font of specific label based on it's value, in your case the font name will be the value.

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896282/how-to-prevent-jcombobox-from-becoming-unresponsive-when-using-a-custom-listcell)